# pandas DataFrame sum method works counterintuitively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
my_df = DataFrame(np.arange(1,13).reshape(4,3), columns=list('abc'))

my_df.sum(axis="rows")
```

O/P is

a    22

b    26

c    30

// I expect it to sum by rows thereby giving

0    6

1    15

2    24

3    33

```
my_df.sum(axis="columns") //helps achieve this
```

Why does it work counterintutively?
In a similar context, drop method works as it should i.e when i write

```
my_df.drop(['a'],axis="columns")
```

// This drops column "a".

Am I missing something? Please enlighten.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short version

It is a naming convention. The sum of the columns gives a row-wise sum. You are looking for `axis='columns')`.

---

#### Long version

Ok that was interesting. In pandas normally 0 is for columns and 1 is for rows.
However looking in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) we find that the allowed params are:

> axis : {index (0), columns (1)}

You are passing a param that does not exist which results in the default. This can thus be read as: The sum of the columns returns the row sum. The sum of the index returns the column sum. What you want to use it `axis=1` or `axis='columns'` which results in your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,13).reshape(4,3), columns=list('abc'))

print(df.sum(axis=1))
```

Returns:

```
0     6
1    15
2    24
3    33
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I do understand all this but shouldn't there be some logic that it was built opposite of what we would think! 
May be there is something which we aren't thinking or grasping.

Comment: @rAmAnA I think the `axis=0|1` (using numbers) is the one that is easier to think of. I can't answer for how other ppl decided to name it but I am very confident they are capable persons that make good decisions. I don't know what other answer you could be seeking.

Comment: With drop(axis = 1) drops columns.
With sum(axis = 1)..sums by row.
So even that is opposite.

Comment: @rAmAnA drop axis1: drop a column. sum axis1: the sum of columns. I think it makes sense.

Comment: may be I am not able to follow but it would help if you can be a bit elaborate. 
sum(axis = 1) is sum of each row . Why do you say it is "sum of columns"?

Comment: @rAmAnA Sum of various columns gives you 1 value (the row-sum). It is just names.